# Can I use the WebBrowser control to load what was actually rendered?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, browser, screen-scraping

I am parsing / scraping data in a web page using c# and the WebBrowser control.  I would like to get the page as rendered, after all Javascript has run; however, loading the document text only loads what is essentially the page source.  I would like the state of the DOM / page after it has been completely processed.  Can I do this with the web browser control?

Note: I am waiting until the document is completely loaded, so that is not the problem.

Comment: I've been reading a lot of places that the WebBrowser control uses the IE7 rendering (and JavaScript) engines (and not the newest IE you have installed locally (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529615/webbrowser-control-and-javascript-errors), that being said once the document is loaded I think you would need to extract the HTML from the DOM and not the page source like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7359217/16959

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572635/webbrowser-behaviour-issues/18573522#18573522) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18675926/1768303) related answers.

Comment: @Jason - thanks; this let me right to the solution that I needed.  -e-