# How to suppress script error message from a web browser control?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

When I load some page  to a `WebBrowser` control for example www.google.iq  it shows an error message

[image]

my code in load event

```
   WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri("https://www.google.com"))
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Javascript

Comment: Can you post the full VB.NET code ? where you are getting this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebBrowser control and JavaScript errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529615/webbrowser-control-and-javascript-errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please set the below property of `WebBrowser` in your form to suppress the script errors of browser and others from the activex control

```
WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```