# How to prevent script error in C# webbrowser?

Tags: javascript

I am getting script error in loading some web sites.

Please help me how to prevent script error in C# WebBrowser.

This is my code:

```
try
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
}
catch(Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("failed");
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you're going to share the script error message, are you?

Comment: This is kinda like hiring a plumber and not telling him what was leaking :p

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Your name is amazing.

Comment: @Wesley:- Wanted to +2 your comment...

Comment: Script error is:

An error has occured in the script on this page

Do you want to continue running script on this page?

Answer (score 4):

Write this in Your Code

```
 webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Comment: where to place it ?

Answer (score 1):

To disable the script error pop up, you need to go to (in Internet Explorer) Tools->Internet Options, there go to the Advanced tab, and in Browsing select Disable Script Debugging (Other), but, the problem may be related to the fact that every site loaded in the WebBrowser control is rendered in IE7 compatibility mode, to solve this the only thing you can do is a registry hack like this: [WebBrowser control to use IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531452/webbrowser-control-to-use-ie9)

Answer (score 0):

change your registry to 2af8 which is IE 11 for devenv.exe
software/Microsoft/internet explorer/main/featurecontrol/feature_Browser_emulation

Answer (score 0):

If your working with a GUI (like in Visual Studio) just go to the Webbrowser Properties and set "ScriptErrorsSuppressed" = true

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see how this error has been eliminated. But Visual Studio uses Internet Explorer and another Web Browser coding is hard. If you look at the versions, the last Visual Studio one uses IE 11 for WebBrowser tool.

The C++ GUI is recommended for one of each encoding:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60k1461a.aspx

Comment: Here is :Chromium Embedded Framework For WebBrowser C#: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8abKzvmTg