# WebBrowser controls keeps freezing, but IE does not

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer

I have a WPF application which hosts a WinForms WebBrowser control. Requirement is to display a page from SAP Web GUI within the web browser control. The page works fine and loads correctly in regular Internet Explorer (version 11). I have tried compatibility modes up to IE 8 and it works fine. But from within the WPF application, it always freezes. I have tried setting FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION and also this suggestion here: [c# Web browser keeps freezing but regular IE9 browser does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395152/c-sharp-web-browser-keeps-freezing-but-regular-ie9-browser-does-not)

The weird thing is, WebBrowser control doesn't get stuck in my VM which has Windows 10 and IE 11. But it gets stuck in my other machine which has Windows 7 and IE 11. I am wondering if there are any IE level or PC level settings that effect WebBrowser performance? I have searched a lot on google and I am out of luck. Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Hosting a WebBrowser control in WPF is problematic at best.

Comment: Users keep reporting this issue. I don't get why it works perfectly fine in my VM and doesn't work in my company imaged laptop. Some settings/policy could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here. Clearing browser cache seems to have fixed the issue. Though it starts getting stuck after some use and cache needs to be cleared again. So I am looking to put in a fix to disable cache when displaying SAP GUI web page in WebBrowser control. If I find anything in regards to that, I will post it here. Until then clearing browser's cache is the solution to this issue.