# Does the WPF 4.0 WebBrowser Control support HTML5 if IE9 is installed?

Tags: c#, wpf, html, internet-explorer-9

Does the WPF 4.0 WebBrowser Control support HTML5 if IE9 is installed? My initial tests with the Video Tag were not successful. Am I wasting my time and the control loads an older version of the Trident Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications that host the WebBrowser control must opt-in to post-IE7 modes using FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION. See [Will the IE9 WebBrowser Control Support all of IE9's features, including SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control)

Comment: I noticed that your link suggests an easier solution if you control the html: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >`. Worked for me!

Comment: Yes, using the Edge mode declaration works for some things, but it behaves differently than using the feature control key.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the hosted version of IE is 7.

Comment: This is unlikely if its suppose to use the same version of IE that is installed on the system.

Comment: Check this one: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test HTML5, but according to the below link on MSDN if IE is updated on the user's PC, the WPF browser control will also be updated since it uses the same version of the IE engine.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/3c99a93c-0eb6-4839-83c9-fdfe72804e87