# How can I make sure the embeded browser control uses Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I installed internet explorer 9 to have it work with the embedded browser control.
After I restarted my computer, it still says I am using IE7.

This is with the .NET Framework 3.5

What do I have to change/update to have the latest version of IE work with the browser control?

Comment: Every site that shows me my user agent, also none of the html5 features are available.

Comment: What version of windows do you have?

Comment: @Alex Mendez Windows 7 x32 bit

Comment: Did you try to change the registry?

Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control

Comment: @leye0 yes I tried that before posting this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control)

If you want to take advantage of new IE9 features, you should add the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >` to the HTML page you're showing.

OR

```
HKLM > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Internet Explorer > Main > FeatureControl > FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

And in there add 'myApplicationName.exe' with value '9000'

Comment: +1. And [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2ed65b9d-c601-4ca8-bde1-64584fc87515/) and [this article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version).

Answer (score -1):

This can be caused by the [Compatibility view](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-to-use-Compatibility-View-in-Internet-Explorer-9).

Check your IE9 config on your system as well as in your winform.

Comment: Compatibility view doesnt change the user agent and is not on by default. Everything works fine in the standalone IE.