# webbrowser control version

Tags: browser, version, gecko

I've read somewhere that the webbrowser control in MS visual studio uses the same engine as the IE installed on my pc. Despite that I found out that this is not correct. And to prove my assumption I used various online browser detecting sites. I present the results here:
(1) IE installed on my pc (both 64-bit and 32-bit):
Browser Information: .
Browser: Microsoft Internet Explorer
Browser Version: 9.0
User Agent String: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

(2) webbrowser control (C#):
Browser Information: 
Browser: Microsoft Internet Explorer 
Browser Version: 7.0 
User Agent String: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

I began to search about it because I had compatibility problems with the webbrowser control whenever I tried to access a specific site (which works fine despite the warnings).
I used gecko 12 to simulate firefox but the site detected that I wasn't using the firefox and I got the warning message again...
So the question is: how can I "cheat" and by-pass detection so that I won't get warning messages after every click? I'm looking for a programmatic way to do so.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no easy way to do this with programming. It's all in the registry.
I can't understand why...
Anyway, the answer is [here](http://www.pedautreppe.com/post/How-can-we-render-CSS3-in-a-WebBrowser-Control-.aspx).
The webbrowser control uses the compatibility mode by default. Even if IE won't use the compatibility mode, the control will.

Answer (score 0):

Webbrowser control uses IE installed on machine. By default it is running in IE 7 compatability mode.
To set your compatability mode you need to list your application in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION with desired compatability mode.