# Browser emulation using Winnovative HTML to PDF

Tags: internet-explorer-9, winnovative

I'm using the [Winnovative HTML to PDF Converter](http://www.winnovative-software.com/Html-To-Pdf-Converter.aspx) tool to convert HTML output pages to PDF files on the server.

To do so, it uses the server's version of Internet Explorer.  Unfortunately, by default that means IE7 mode, no matter what the server has.  I have IE9 on the server, and need to make the converter use that mode.

Other discussions, e.g. [Regarding IE9 WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control), talk about adding a value to this registry key (or its 64 bit version, or both) to set the emulation mode:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

However, to add the needed key, you need to know what EXE or DLL is being used. I've tried "wnvhtmlconvert.dll" but that doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone figured out what value to put in the registry to get this to work?

Comment: Turns out that the same vendor now has another version of this software (http://www.evopdf.com/) that does not use IE for rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it...

My IIS server is running under w3wp.exe, 32 bit (as seen in the Windows Task Manager).

Added a DWORD value, Name=w3wp.exe, Value=9000 (decimal) to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

Then recycled the IIS application pool.

Now, the converter is using IE9 to process the HTML into PDF!

Comment: I have tried but it's not working in my PC.do you have any idea ?