# TEmbeddedWB / TWebbrowser mouse lag (object drag and drop)

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer-9, mouse, lag, twebbrowser

I use a TEmbeddedWB in a Delphi project to display a HTML5/CSS3/Javascript game fullscreen. It uses IE9 embedded to render the page. That is working fine but i discover some lag, speed difference compared to other browsers and IE9 itself (when the page is loaded in the browser itself). In a browser there is no lag.

Because the game uses drag and drop features to move objects and can be used on touchscreens, the lag in movements is a little annoying.

I tried several things, disable background drawing, repainting, increase CPU priority above normal, disable TEmbeddedWB features etc. I also tried it with TWebBrowser but has the same issues.

Anybody any idea how to solve this? Found nothing on the internet about this.

Comment: Do you have a link to the game so we can try it out ourselves?

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Sorry, can do that because it is for an client of mine and it will be an store app on several platforms. But, my question is clear right? There is no lag in the browser but only in the embedded version. Code of game is the same.

Comment: You can try [Chromium embedded framework](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/)

Comment: Yes, I know. But it will be easier that there is a solution to this because the project is almost finished and don't have the time to switch and IE9 is acceptable and no external dll's needed.

Comment: Are you sure you are running in [IE9 Mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5357168/800214)

Comment: Yes, because you see rounded corners, gradients and all that kind of stuff ;-). You won't see this in IE7 mode ;-). Also set this to IE9 mode (check this before display TEmbeddedWB).

Comment: @Erwinus - what do you mean with "no external dll's needed?" That's hardly an advantage when using `TEmbeddedWB`...

Comment: @Leonardo: You don't need any extra dll's because it is already available in Windows. It uses for example WININET.DLL and URLMON.DLL, already available on the system like other API libraries. Just one executable to deploy.

Comment: @Erwinus - yes, I know that. I hope you are aware that there are many versions out there. It's just that I would never again develop a commercial product relying on the IE control; it's a moving target, and during my time it was a support nightmare.

Comment: @Leonardo: Yes, i know, but the requirement is that you must at least IE9 installed. When it was not possible to use IE9, i tried another solution. All other earlier IE-crap is not supported. Also, the 'loader' does nothing special, only display content, no fancy things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

23 days later:

IE10 pre release is yet launched (today) for Windows 7. Download and installed it, problem of lag is gone.

The Javascript engine of IE10 is much faster comparing to IE9. I think that is the problem.

Although it is not a real solution (problem of lag with IE9 Embedded still persists) but looks promising for the near future. My requirements are at least IE9 to operate but when you want more speed and more HTML5/CSS3 support you must upgrade to IE10.
But, if you find a solution for IE9 in the future, please let me know.

To download a pre release of IE10, you can visit this page (i downloaded the 64 bit version).
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35709

Answer (score 0):

As said previously, check which IE mode you're using. Also, check the code you're running in the EmbeddedWB events, particularly the mouse events.

Comment: As I said before in the comments above, I do check the version. Installed IE version and embeded version (exe key in registry Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION). Can you explain how to turn off mouse events?