# WebBrowser style not applying properly in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

This is the HTML code I use in my WinForms application:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #vif {
    margin:20px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color:#888;
    }
    #inf li {
    margin-left:40px;
    color:#fff;
    }
    #inf {
    margin-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vif">
    <div id="inf">
        <li>Hello!</li>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I save personally and used IE9 to display, it works fine, but when the `WebBrowser` uses it, the `margin-top` on `#inf` was not applied. Why? Isn't it the same IE I use? The same code display differently!

The proper render should have a gray box with margin around it and the white text should fix in the middle.

How to display properly using `WebBrowser`?

Comment: What IE version do you have?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici IE10, but this works also in IE9, but didn't they say the WebBrowser is the same IE you have?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4613025/43846

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your HTML's header section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help! and CodeCaster's

Answer (score 2):

If the problem really is compatibility, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4613025/266143):

> WebBrowser control will use whatever version of IE you have installed, but for compatibility reasons it will render pages in IE7 Standards mode by default.
>
> If you want to take advantage of new IE9 features, you should add the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` inside the `<head>` tag of your HTML page.