# HTML5 for c# Web Browser

Tags: c#, html

I have create simple Web Browser using c# and it read html pages well,but it doesn't read any html5 pages.i want to know how to enable that.

Comment: Web browser? I don't get it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Giving answer to your question almost imposible. What is your work? What have you tried? What is your aim? Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: I used web browser control in c# to navigate specify url. the page of url was created with html5.but the url doesn't read ,it shown "Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question by assuming you're asking about the WebBrowser class.

If you're trying to say that you used a WebBrowser class to read HTML pages but it doesn't read HTML5 pages, it could be because your IE version doesn't support HTML5. Did you install IE9? [WebBrowser simply wraps the IE installed in your computer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4613025)

Comment: I used web browser control in c# to navigate specify url. the page of url was created with html5.but the url doesn't read ,its show "Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag".