# Updated WebBrowser control WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, browser

I know that we can include the WebBrowser control in our WinForms applications. But, how can we use the one that is used by IE 9 or 10? As far as I'm aware, the one that comes with Visual Studio is the same old one being used since a thousand years ago.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4613025/187697

Comment: WebBrowser is just a small .NET wrapper class for the **installed** version of IE.