# geolocation in Delphi7 TWebBrowser

Tags: html, delphi, geolocation, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser

I've made a simple web-service that returns geolocation, and it works just fine when it requests from IE10, Chrome, Firefox. (all of them are latest versions)
But, if I call same request from Delphi's (ver 7) TWebBrowser, there is response: "request is not supported by your browser" (or something like this).

It seems to me that it could be a HTML5 issue, which is not supported by Delphi's TWebBrowser component.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IE8 and later versions render pages running within instances of the WebBrowser control in IE7 Standards Mode by default, but this can be overriden. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4613025/859646 (answer and comments).

Comment: Yes, you have to jump through hoops to make the IE control display using modern standards. The same applies for HTML help. I do expect that the registry opt-in described by JRL will do the trick.

Comment: JRL is correct, been there and done that with several of my apps now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TWebBrowser` is just a thin wrapper for Internet Explorer's core engine via ActiveX.  So whatever version of IE you have installed, that is the same version that `TWebBrowser` should be using and representing itself to websites, and being the same core engine, it should support all/most of the same features that the IE browser app supports.  So it does not make sense for the IE10 browser app to work correctly but `TWebBrowser` to not work.  You will have to use a packet sniffer, like Wireshark or Fiddler, to see what `User-Agent` header `TWebBrowser` is actually sending and see whether it is different than what IE10 sends.

Comment: Please, see my comment to the question