# Visual Studio web browser CSS3 support

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, css, browser

How can i enable css3 in my c# application WebBrowser element? Somewhat like in [this](http://www.pedautreppe.com/post/How-can-we-render-CSS3-in-a-WebBrowser-Control-.aspx) thread?

I'm running IE 10 on windows 8.1

`Browser.Version` says 11.0.9600.16476

Comment: If I read the blog you're referring to, you need to make sure that at least IE9 or a higher version is installed on the computer that runs your application and you need to set some Windows Registry settings on that computer as well. Did you try that?

Comment: i need this program to run on other computers as well, so it would be helpfull to know hot to do that from the programm

Comment: WebBrowser  browser = new WebBrowser();
Version ver = browser.Version;
If the version < 9, then you need to inform the user to upgrade his browser?

Comment: it says 11.0.9600.16476 and doesn't run css 3

Comment: Follow Tinwor's link below, it explains how to tweak your registry and probably the html you're showing. 
ps. Don't try to update IE yourself, I think informing the user is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The css3 rendering in the WebBrowser userControl it depends on the version of IE that you have installed on your machine. So I reccomend you to upgrade to the latest version. If it dosen't work you need to change a registry Key: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control).

If you want use another WebBrowser like chrome try [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)(chromium porting for c#)

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser element in WPF uses your local install of Internet Explorer to render the html, so if you have IE8, then it will support CSS 2.1 and a few CSS3 rules. IE 9 and 10 will support even more CSS3 rules, however not all of them.

Comment: You'll have to look at another browser control, because the WebControl will behave differently on other machines. Here is a good Chromium Webrowser Control that will work well with you .NET applicaiton: http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/ Using this will allow you to use CSS3 and it will look the same on everyone's machine

Comment: I agree with Alec. The WebControl has some very strange behaviors. But if it's only to show simple html files with not much Javascript and no advanced css3, it might be a lot easier than moving to Chromium...