# Ability to support Html5 in WPF webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, html, browser

My WPF browser does not support html5 elements on webpages, and I do not know how to implement support for it. I do have IE9 installed and I can see html5 elements browsing with IE.

Any help with how I can go about adding support for html5 is very much appreciated.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually found out the solution by myself. Everything is explained on this page: http://kirubhananth.blogspot.se/2013/04/how-to-load-html-5-content-in-wpf.html

1. Click Start -> Run (or `Win+R` shortcut)
2. Type `REGEDIT` in the textbox and click enter. The Registry Editor will be opened. Needs administration rights to open and modify the registry.
3. Traverse in the tree in left side panel through `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Wow6432Node -> Microsoft -> Internet Explorer -> MAIN -> FeatureControl -> FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`
4. After selecting the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` right click the empty space in the right side keys panel and select `New -> DWORD (32 bit) Value`
5. Set the value name as your app's name. eg: `MyApp.exe`
6. Set the vaule data to 270f and tick Hexadecimal.
7. To support debugging through Visual Studio, add another key with the same value data and with `.vshost` between your app name and the extension. eg: `MyApp.vshost.exe`

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: To enable the same feature while debugging in Visual studio, add another key with the same value, but name the key: YouAppName.vshost.exe, and it will work!

Comment: vvolkgang, what do you put as the app name when you are debugging and launching the application from Visual Studio?  I've added MyApp.exe 0x2af9 (for ie 11) to the registry.  And if I launch the app by double clicking on the executable in explorer in runs.  But if I try and launch it from Visual Studio in order to debug it, I still get a browser not supported error from the website that it is attempted to interact with.