# WPF Webbrowser FlashPlayer

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any possibility Web Browser support to demonstrate youtube videos?
[image]

Comment: Not sure about Flash support but maybe you could give this solution a shot? [Ability to support Html5 in WPF webbrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522730/ability-to-support-html5-in-wpf-webbrowser)

Comment: You answered to my question, thank you PakkuDon !