# WPF WebBrowser compatability with Google street view

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, google-street-view

I am using WPF `WebBrowser`:

```
<WebBrowser Name="wbTest""/>
```

and navigating into

```
wbTest.Navigate("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=40.782001,73.831703")
```

But the WebBrowser is showing on this Google street view page the following Internet Explorer Compatibility issue on top of the browser:

[image]

How can this be removed? Following the link [Learn how to do this](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3118069?p=newmaps_ie&rd=1) will only give instructions regarding Internet Explorer regular browser but can something be done to WPF `WebBrowser` to get rid of this message?

Comment: Whats your IE version

Comment: I have 10.0. But I can't know what version the users of the application will have.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the error by changing the engine used by the webbrowser as I explained there:

[Set WPF webbrowser control to use IE10 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776951/set-wpf-webbrowser-control-to-use-ie10-mode/23777041#23777041)

I tried and the warning is not showing, but i have some graphical glitches.