# Filter Gridview by textbox changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, gridview

I've searched the interwebs long and wide for an answer to my question, though nothing worked. 
I have an existing gridview in C# WCF, that gets its data by an sql datasource. 
I want to have it filter after what ever is input the textbox. 
The thing is that when I am trying to follow some of the methods I found I always get a null value or nothing is changed.

---

I've tried the following:

```
private void tbSearchContracts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  BindingSource src = new BindingSource();
  src.DataSource = dgvPapers.DataSource;
  src.Filter = string.Format("PaperName like '%{0}%'", tbSearchContracts.Text.Trim());
  dgvPapers.DataSource = src;
  dgvPapers.Refresh();
}
```

This doesn't give me an error, but simply just refreshes the view, as if the filter is never applied.

This is another solution I've found and tried:

```
private void tbSearchContracts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  (dgvPapers.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("PaperName like '%{0}%'", tbSearchContracts.Text.Trim());
}
```

Where this returns null when trying to convert the datasource to a datatable.

*dgvPapers.DataSource is returning a list of Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing was not the cleanest way, but i found it to be the easieast way to get things done.

```
  List<Object> products = ((IEnumerable)dgvPapers.DataSource).Cast<object>().ToList();
  List<ContractPaperStepDTO> altered = new List<ContractPaperStepDTO>();
  foreach (var item in products)
  {
    altered.Add((ContractPaperStepDTO)item);
  }
  altered = altered.Where(c => c.PaperName.ToLower().Contains(tbSearchContracts.Text.ToLower())).ToList();
  dgvPapers.DataSource = altered;
  dgvPapers.Update();
}
```

Comment: Your `dgvPapers.Update();` line will constantly make a trip to the database thus hampering your performance drastically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that worked for me with the help of JQuery:

**Step 1: SQL** Write a Stored Procedure (accepting one input parameter) to Retrieve Paper Names from your database (Assuming you're using SQL Server as a DBMS):

```
create proc [dbo].[spGetMatchingPaperIds]
@PaperId nvarchar(Whatever size)
as
begin
select PaperId from TableStoringYourPaperIds where PaperId like @PaperId + '%'
end
GO
```

**Step 2: Web Service**
Create a web service (and name it PaperSearchService.asmx or whatever naming convention you follow) and write a function that will query your database and retrieve a list of your paper names like so:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<string> getPaperNames(string DeviceIdString)
    {
        List<string> paperNames = new List<string>();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringToTheDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetMatchingPaperIds", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@PaperId", PaperId);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                paperNames.Add(rdr["PaperId"].ToString());
            }
        }

        return paperNames;
    }
```

**Step 3: HTML Markup**
I'm assuming you are using a master page so this should go inside one of your content placeholders.

Use developer tools to check for JQuery errors that it may throw on your browser by clicking **F12** while debugging and download the relevant JQuery library from the CDN and just include it in your master page but last time I checked its `jquery-1.7.min.js` - just double check. This aforementioned library has the autocomplete functionality otherwise it won't work.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
                $('#<%= tbSearchContracts.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "PaperSearchService.asmx/getPaperNames",
                            data: "{ 'PaperId': '" + request.term + "' }",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                response(data.d);
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 0
                });
            });

           //Below are some nice-to-have's:
           function CreateWaterMark(defaultText, textBoxControl) {
            if (textBoxControl.value.length == 0) {
                textBoxControl.style.color = "gray";
                textBoxControl.value = defaultText;
            }
        }

        function ClearWaterMark(defaultText, textBoxControl) {
            if (textBoxControl.value == defaultText) {
                textBoxControl.style.color = "black";
                textBoxControl.value = "";
            }
        }
       </script>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbSearchContracts" CssClass="whatever styling you have used" onblur="CreateWaterMark('Search Paper Names Here', this);" onfocus="ClearWaterMark('Search Paper Names Here', this);" onkeyup="hasPendingChanges()" Text="Search Paper Names Here" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Sadly iam not using this on a webpage but in a wcf application.

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft WCF is meant for service implementation which can be consumed by multiple clients e.g windows forms application, website, etc. You have an event `private void tbSearchContracts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` which I am assuming is a button click or some form of control on a WPF or WinForms application acting as a client consuming your service calls. You can still achieve the above if you add a test WinForms application to your solution and include a Web Browser control to call the JQuery function in a script tag.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095271/how-to-embed-jquery-in-a-winforms-app-to-use-in-a-webbrowser-control

Comment: That is actually kinda interesting, i will have a look at that!

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft If this implementation helps you please feel free to give it an upvote. Happy coding.