# Opening a 3D scene in WPF using WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, wpf, webbrowser-control

I modeled and rendered a 3D scene using `Marmoset Toolbag` and exported it to a `Viewer file`. This will give me a `.mscene` file and a `html` file. All I have to do is to put them in the same folder and open a `html` file with a browser that has `webgl` activated and it works. It works using `FireFox` for example. 
However, when I wish to load it to my `grid` in my WPF app, it just says errors, like _ Script error: error in the page's command_ (error message is my translation sorry). *Error code: 0. Line: 0, Character: 0.* I always say to continue but in the end All I get is a blank page. 
This is the code I wrote to open it up:

```
private void ShowDumbbellMethod()
{
    var targetGrid = (parent as BrowseWares).ViewerGrid;
    var viewer = new WebBrowser();

    viewer.Source = new Uri("C:\\Users\\agoston\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\HP_hf_shop\\HP_hf_shop\\HTML\\dumbbell.html");

    targetGrid.Children.Add(viewer);

}
```

The `URI` points to my project for now.

How to get this to work? All I saw on the internet was webgl with `WebControl` dated back to 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebGL is supported only in IE11 while WPF's WebBrowser control uses IE7 engine by default. But it's possible to make WebBrowser to use the latest engine. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776951/set-wpf-webbrowser-control-to-use-ie10-mode) to know how to do it, please.

Alternatively, you can use [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) instead of WebBrowser control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
The app will have to run on other machines as well so I can't force everyone to modify the registry. I tried adding the line into the HTML file, but to no avail. Maybe I should try the CefSharp thing

Comment: Nope, no luck with cef either (or I'm this noob, also possible). Shall I check for other browser plugins? If so, is there a Firefox? That did good when I just opened it up in file explorer.