# show google earth in c# webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, google-earth

since some days google earth is directly available via browsers like edge or internetexplorer. However, if a create a Webbrowser control in wpf and navigate to google.com/maps and click on "satellite view", the website tells me, that google earth view is not available for me. 
Compare both views:

Images can be found here: 
http://wb20.stedum-bekum.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Webbrowser.png 
http://wb20.stedum-bekum.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/IE.png

*the yellow rectangle sais: 3d View not available

In my code i set User Agent manuelly and update it via urlmon in the navigating event.

```
webbrowser.Navigate(new Uri("https://google.de/maps"), null, null, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko \r\n");
```

and

```
   [DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
   private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(
   int dwOption, string pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);

    const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;
    const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH = 0x10000002;

    public void ChangeUserAgent(string agent)
    {

        UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH, null, 0, 0);
        UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, agent, agent.Length, 0);
    }
```

and i also changed webbrowser to behave like ie via FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

does anybody have an idea how to use it in webbrowser?

I also tried dotnetbrowser to integrate. This worked for some days, but now i get the same message.

I also tried firefox, edge and chrome (outside of my code), they are all working fine like IE.

Comment: Can't view your images

Comment: http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: i uploaded the images to a second server

Comment: I think the webview uses IE9 as backend by default (which maybe doesn't support webgl). There is a topic on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776951/set-wpf-webbrowser-control-to-use-ie10-mode

Comment: I already use feature browser emulation to behave like ie11.

Answer (score 0):

I found out. For anyone who need the same, the problem was Webbrowser Hardware acceleration is turned off by default. You can set

FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING to 1 in Registry as statet here 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330731(v=VS.85).aspx