# Show HTML5 Dialog In Delphi

Tags: html, delphi, mshtml

I'm currently using the ShowHTMLDialog that in MSHTML.DLL to display a html document embedded in my application as a modal dialogue.

This all work OK but I would like to be able to have better looking dialogues so am trying to move to HTML5, I have found the following example of an html 5 login page but it does not display correctly when loaded form my application.

Example Login
http://cssdeck.com/labs/login-form-using-html5-and-css3

My Questions are: is this is even possible and if so what's the best way to go about it.

Heres is what I am seeing  [image: Login Image]
I am expecting it to look like the website posted above,

Running windows 7 and IE 11

The code I am using in Delphi is

```
LibHandle := LoadLibrary('MSHTML.DLL');
@ShowHTMLDialog:=GetProcAddress(LibHandle,'ShowHTMLDialog');
URLStr:=StringToOleStr(AMessage);
CreateURLMoniker(nil, URLStr,pmk);
SysFreeString(URLStr);

TVarData(InParam).VType := varOleStr;
TVarData(InParam).VOleStr:=StringToOleStr(FParams);

AParams := AParams + Format('dialogHeight:%d pt;',[AHeight]);
AParams := AParams + Format('dialogWidth:%d pt;',[AWidth]);
AParams := AParams + Format('center:%s;',['no']);
AParams := AParams + Format('unadorned:%s;',['yes']);
AParams := AParams + Format('dialogTop:%d px;',[ATop]);
AParams := AParams + Format('dialogLeft:%d px;',[ALeft]);

Features := PWideChar(AParams);
// display window
ShowHTMLDialog( hwndParent, pmk, InParam, Features, OutParam);
FreeLibrary(LibHandle);
```

Comment: Microsoft's page for the function I'm using. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Are the features you're trying to use supported by the version of Internet Explorer you have? What code did you write, what results did you get, and what results did you expect instead?

Comment: The page look fine if I open it in explorer. But in my app it just looks like a basic form

Comment: webbrowser control may default to a different mode than the browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control

Comment: Tried those settings and it still does not display correctly

Comment: Why use ShowHTMLDialog rather than the web browser control?

Comment: it returns arguments from the form, and the source page comes from a res file

Comment: All things that are possible with the web browser control

Comment: An aside. Your code completely ignores error checking. Always check for errors.

Comment: I only added the functional code, and excluded the check and debug logging to keep it short, I don't think it possible to do what I want with that function, so will have to look at a different method, currently checking out DCEF TChromium,

Comment: It's possible with ease with the browser control