# unable to login with WebBrowser Control

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, webbrowser-control

I have developed an Embedded WebBrowser using IE webbrowser control in C++. Now, there is a strange problem. I am not able to login to one particular website. I am able to login the same website using IE or chrome or mozilla. But with Embedded Browser I am not. It seems like it is waiting for the response. But I am able to login to my gmail account with my WebBrowser. With the packet tracer I observed that there was very few request/response generated from Embedded WebBrowser as compared to any other normal browser. I can only see the cgi scripts request being called by my WebBrowser unlike other browser which also issued CSS and JS request.

Anyone have any idea that why this strange behaviour? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the website doesn't work with IE7?   The browser control is forced into IE7 compatibility [mode by default](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility.aspx).

Try accessing the site with regular IE in compatibility mode.  If it fails the same way, you have your answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't close this question as I already solved it. Yes it was IE7 problem. I did saw this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control
and when I check the response headers then there was `content IE tag`, so I thought it must be working on IE11(the version installed on my system) but it was not. And I also changed the registry but did a slight mistake. My app is 32bit and system is 64bit, so I was suppose to change it in WOW6432NODE key, which I did not. Stupid me. Wasted 4 days on this silly problem.