# Is the WebBrowser control equivalent to IE?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Today I started to write a very primitive web browser, and decided to use the `WebBrowser` control in winforms. After using it to go to stackoverfloe.com, I see that it cannot run JavaScript. Also the layout is really weird. It seems like someone has blown up the page. The buttons (questions, tags, users etc) were all off their original positions!

I just want to know whether WebControl is just a simplified IE, because no other browsers would display webpages like they were blown up.

Comment: It is, yes. You can modify the registry to make it slightly better, but if you need a fully fledged browsing experience you'll need something like CefSharp. See the accepted answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control/4613025) for the registry keys.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! @Equalsk