# .Net Webbrowser Control not displaying accurately

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a winforms app in which I am using a Webbrowser control but the control doesn't seem to be accurately displaying an HTML document that I'm loading (the document is stored on the local PC).

When I preview the document in IE or Chrome it looks correct:

[image]

When the HTML is rendered in the Webbrowser control all the spacing is removed and it looks like this:

[image]

Both previews are on a Windows 10 computer running IE 11.1198. If the webbrowser control is using IE to render the HTML, I don't understand why the two are different and how can I fix the rendering in the webbrowser control?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/will-the-ie9-webbrowser-control-support-all-of-ie9s-features-including-svg is what you are looking for (probably can be closed as duplicate).

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303

Comment: Thanks so much @AlexeiLevenkov the link you provided contained a solution for me. Adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >` to the header of the html document did the trick.