# Script error when webbrowser loading html page

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

I'm trying to load local html page using webbrowser tool in Winforms but I got script error message and my page won't load, when I open that page using any web browser it opens with no problem at all! I tried some solutions as editing registry but no fix.
my html page has jscript code and this is the code in my page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js?cacheBust=56"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
var csatGauge = new FusionCharts({
    "type": "angulargauge",
    "renderAt": "chart-container",
    "width": "400",
    "height": "250",
    "dataFormat": "json",
        "dataSource": {
               "chart": {
                  "caption": "Customer Satisfaction Score",
                  "subcaption": "Last week",
                  "lowerLimit": "0",
                  "upperLimit": "100",
                  "theme": "fint"
               },
               "colorRange": {
                  "color": [
                     {
                        "minValue": "0",
                        "maxValue": "50",
                        "code": "#e44a00"
                     },
                     {
                        "minValue": "50",
                        "maxValue": "75",
                        "code": "#f8bd19"
                     },
                     {
                        "minValue": "75",
                        "maxValue": "100",
                        "code": "#6baa01"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "dials": {
                  "dial": [
                     {
                        "value": "67"
                     }
                  ]
               }
        }
  });

csatGauge.render();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart-container">An angular guage will load here!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the "script error message"?

Comment: There is typo in "scripttype" on the 3rd line. Is it correct in your code?

Comment: typo <scripttype=" it should be <script type=" your code works fine after doing changes.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgbbdY

Comment: It is: expected identifier string or number, line 42, char 1

Comment: I edited the code, this is my code that generates the error

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve it by adding this code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
</head>
```

I'm still not sure if this is only thing needed or it worked with the change of the registry: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/will-the-ie9-webbrowser-control-support-all-of-ie9s-features-including-svg/5357168#5357168)